# Access attribute value inside template in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive and passed attribute as object(name/value pair) of string. However if i try to access the attribute value inside the template, it is not getting evaluated. 
The attribute is passed like below

```
<testcomponent  myInfo="{firstname:'green',lastname:'Woods'}"></testcompone>
```

The template is define like below

```
   template: '<div>This will not run fine..! </div>'+
        '<div> This first name is: {{myInfo.firstname}} </div>',
```

I have created an islolated scope like below

```
  scope: {
       info: '=myInfo',
    },
```

The jsfiddle is @https://jsfiddle.net/visibleinvisibly/be4ww6vu/

The variable({{myInfo.firstname}}) needs to be evaluated but it is not happening.I am looking for a solution which doesnt need to create a controller(i am be wrong too)

Thanks in advance,
jason

Comment: I'd rather suggest you to create an array of name value pair and pass the name of array in the attribute value. Try this and let me know if that works

Comment: Thank you for creating a fiddle.  Made this substantially easier to answer!

Comment: One more quick note - in your fiddle, you were using Angular 1.0 - I'm hoping that you are actually using / able to use 1.4+?  There are some differences that would benefit you.  (2.0 is different, so if you are learning angular, you MAY want to consider learning 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems (identified below) and a few tips for using Angular as well.

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/be4ww6vu/12/)

1. Angular is case-sensitive, and "particular" about attribute names.  If you want your attribute to be `myInfo` in your directive, then in the markup you need to set it as `my-info`.  Angular automatically adapts the name from `my-info` in the markup into `myInfo` in the directive.
2. Your markup (where you are attempting to output the name) references `myInfo`, however your scope declaration assigns that to the scope variable `info`.  In order to output the name, you need to change it to `{{info.firstname}}`.

Below is the revise code, with comments:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" >
  <!-- Issue #2: If you want camel-case "myInfo", angular expects the attribute to be "my-info". -->
  <test-component   
  my-info="{firstname: 'green',lastname: 'Woods'}"/>
</div>
```

And the directive:

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', [])
    .directive('testComponent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        // Issue #1: The template referenced 'myInfo', but your scope was assigning that to 'info'.
        template: '<div>This will not run fine..! </div>'+
        '<div> This first name is: {{info.firstname}} </div>',
        scope: {
           /* Hints: 
                = is two way-binding "deep" watch.  
                =* is "shallow" watch, and on this simple object, that is all you need.  
                @ is text-binding (for reference)
           */
           info: '=*myInfo',
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    };
});
```

Lastly - normally (in my experience) you would not set the value of the attribute directly in the markup, but rather you would reference a `$scope` variable from your controller, and assign the value in your controller.

Comment: @visibleinvisibly - glad I could help.  if this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.